# EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include Method equivalent in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, entity-framework, orm

Is there any equivalent of EntityFramework Core [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-2.1) method in Python or Django ORM methods? If not how can I include related entities in the query results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)?